# How to find out duplicate AWS CloudWatch Alarms

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I am trying to delete all cloud watch alarms which is not in use.
Any suggestions on How to find out duplicate AWS CloudWatch Alarms?

Comment: How do you define "not in use", and what do you mean by "duplicate alarms"?

Comment: The CW alarms still exist but the resources are got deleted are the alarms not in use , the duplicate alarms are more than one CW alarms for same resource and same metrics but in different name. How to filter those kind of alarms in an automated way?

Comment: You would need to write a program that calls the CloudWatch APIs to obtain a listing of the alarms. Then, for each resource referenced, make API calls to determine whether the resource exists. For the duplicates, you could compare all alarm to each other (again, via a program you write) to identify duplicates.